Import iCal (ics) with fullcalendar, working example?
Ok apparently its not possible here to ask a follow-on question to an old thread like this on Fullcalendar
How do I import an ical URL feed into the Fullcalendar javascript module? All old(!) examples on this issue do not work. Others report CORS error when trying to access an ical URL.
Does anyone have a working example (html plus javascript) for this function?
Thanks, Haegar
Following the thread above , trying the example on the fullcalendar website. Like
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import iCalendarPlugin from '@fullcalendar/icalendar'

var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [dayGridPlugin, iCalendarPlugin],
  events: {
    url: 'https://my_example_remote_site/test.ics',
    format: 'ics'
  }
})

calendar.render()

In the working directory I installed the modules:
npm install ical.js --save
npm install fullcalendar --save

which results in errors like dayGridPlugin not found
With other methods (html page with javascript embedded) I get also problems accessing the libraries or getting CORS errors??

You can only load ical feeds from your own domain (same as the website on which you are displaying the fullcalendar), it's expected to get CORS errors for other sources.

Please provide a [mre] of your specific issue, with code sample and the exact error message / unexpected output you're getting. Otherwise we can only really guess at the precise nature of the problem. As mentioned above, a CORS error would be expected when accessing a cross-origin URL, if the provider of that URL doesn't set CORS headers. But that's just normal browser behaviour and has nothing to do with fullCalendar. It's a bit unclear precisely where you're having difficulty, from your rather vague description. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post, and we can try to help more. Thanks.

P.S. The example on the fullCalendar website works absolutely fine, if you provide it with a valid URL for the ics file, and the ics file itself is also valid.

In the working directory I installed the modules...you don't seem to have installed the daygrid module, looking at those commands

Hmm it should be. Or has the module another name? That's why I was hoping for a complete code example not just sniplets?

There's a fullcalendar core module and then daygrid is a separate one as far as I know - look at the plugin list in the fullcalendar documentation. I'm talking about your npm install commands btw). As I don't load my calendar like this (I just use script tags) I can't give you the precise answer, I'm just trying to help where I can
